# Motor power rotating, with weight difference

Tags: power, motor, rotor

If the motor is rotating a large rotor, and the mechanical resistance increasing with rpm, will the power consumption be the same even if there is a difference in weight on the rotor during steady-state operation?

In a system where a motor rotates a rotor at a constant speed and there is a substantial mechanical resistance, is the power consumption affected by the weight difference in the rotor, especially when considering the need for additional acceleration to offset the deceleration component caused by increased mechanical resistance?

Comment: You need to _edit your question_ for clarity.  Is the mechanical resistance the same in the light rotor and heavy rotor case?  Are you talking about cases where the motor speed is steady, cases where the motor speed is changing at a constant rate, or something else?

Comment: write the equations for mechanical resistance as a function of speed, weight, and any other factor that you might want to include - air pressure, or state of lubrication for instance. In your second 'constant speed' paragraph, why do you talk about acceleration, it's obviously zero as you've specified constant speed.